# ListView android , marca itens de forma errada

Tags: android, listview

Tenho uma lista em que eu marco os itens da seguinte forma `:view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_row)`, toda vez que eu clicar ele precisa setar a cor. Quando eu clicar denovo, ele seta a linha escura. Até aí tudo certo, porém, quando rolo a lista para baixo ele "marca" o itens que estão abaixo da lista.

Segue o trecho de código:

```
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
    // get all songs from sdcard
    this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();
    // looping through playlist
    for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsListData.add(song);
    }
    // Adding menuItems to ListView
     final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
            R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.songTitle2 });


    setListAdapter(adapter);


    ListView lv = getListView();
    // listening to single listitem click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        int flag1 = 0;
        int flag2 = 0;

        int auxPosicao1 = -1;//primeira vez
        int auxPosicao2 = -1;//primeira vez

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            View lastRow = null;        
            if (lastRow != null) {
                lastRow.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
                }
            if (flag1==0 &&((auxPosicao1 == position || (auxPosicao1 == -1 && auxPosicao2==-1)))){
                flag1 = 1;
                auxPosicao1 = position;
                aux = position;
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_row);

            }else if(auxPosicao1==position)
            {           
                if (flag2 == 1){

                    aux = aux2;
                    auxPosicao1 = auxPosicao2;  

                    aux2 = -1;
                    flag2 =0;
                    auxPosicao2 =-1;

                }else{
                    aux = -1;
                    flag1=0;
                    auxPosicao1 =-1;

                }
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_row2);

            }else if(flag2 == 0 &&((auxPosicao2 == position || auxPosicao2 == -1))){
                aux2 = position;
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_row);
                flag2 = 1;
                auxPosicao2 = position;

            }else if(position == auxPosicao2){
                aux2 = -1;
                flag2 =0;
                auxPosicao2 =-1;
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_row2);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Coming soon ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //lastRow = view;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Diogo, acho que esse tipo de lógica precisa passar pelo `Adapter` (dar ao `Adapter` a responsabilidade de "pintar" as linhas quando clicadas). Digo isso porque o "algoritmo de reciclagem" do `ListView é quem causa esse problema, de elementos que você não clicou estarem com a cor quando não deveriam. Vou tentar montar um código para te ajudar, mas vai ficar um pouco grande.

Comment: blz coloquei adapter para se te ajudar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit

Como a intenção era fazer um algoritmo de seleção de linhas, a solução anterior não atendia por completo, tornando a nova solução mais simples.

Na nova solução, o `Adapter` possui um `SparseArray` (poderia ser um `HashMap`, mas o `SparseArray` é mais recomendando na plataforma Android).

Para cada posicao, o `SparseArray` ou guarda 1 para a posição se ela ta marcada ou 0 caso contrário.

Como pedido, o segundo clique desmarca o item, como um checkbox.

```
public class TestBaseAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    // Armazena as linhas que possuem cliques, para marcação
    SparseArray<Integer> mCliques = new SparseArray<Integer>();

    // Usado para adicionar um valor a uma View, no metodo setTag
    int mResId;

    public TestBaseAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        mResId = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        updateBackground(view, position);

        // Guardo na View, sua posicao
        // Facilita ao fazer a limpeza manual do background caso seja necessario
        view.setTag(mResId, position);

        return view;
    }

    /***
     * Atualiza o background da View conforme a regra de cliques
     * @param view
     * @param position
     */
    void updateBackground(View view, int position) {
        // Se houve nao tem clique, entao remove o background
        if(mCliques.get(position, 0) == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(0);
        } else { // Adiciona o background em caso positivo
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.primary);
        }
    }

    /***
     * Atualiza a ultima posicao clicada e o numero de cliques.
     * E atualiza o Background da view conforme o resultado
     * @param adapterView
     * @param view
     * @param position
     */
    public void updateClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position) {

        // Se a posicao foi clicada e ja estava marcada, remove a marcação
        if(mCliques.get(position, -1) != -1) {
            mCliques.remove(position);
        } else { // Adiciona a marcação
            mCliques.put(position, 1);
        }

        // Podemos usar o "notifyDataSetChanged", com isso todas as Views
        // que estao visiveis serao reconstruidas
        // notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Ou podemos atualizar manualmente as visiveis, as demais
        // serao construídas pelo Adapter
        updateVisibleViews(adapterView);
    }

    void updateVisibleViews(AdapterView adapterView) {
        for(int i = 0, childCount = adapterView.getChildCount(); i < childCount; ++i) {
            View view = adapterView.getChildAt(i);
            int position = (Integer) view.getTag(mResId);

            updateBackground(view, position);
        }
    }

    /***
     * Retorna a lista dos indices dos itens selecionados
     * @return
     */
    public ArrayList<Integer> getSelectedItems() {
        ArrayList<Integer> selecao = new ArrayList<Integer>(mCliques.size());

        for(int i = 0, size = mCliques.size(); i < size; ++i) {
            selecao.add(mCliques.keyAt(i));
        }

        return selecao;
    }
}
```

---

Para realizar essa tarefa, é preciso criar uma subclasse do `SimpleAdapter`, porque precisamos incorporar a regra de "coloração" ao `Adapter`, ficando mais simples e dando a responsabilidade para o elemento correto.

Fiz um exemplo de como pode ser feito, minha solução é apenas uma base, bastando adaptar para o seu caso específico.

Como não tenho os mesmos dados que você, tive que improvisar:

Essa é a construção do `Adapter` e dos dados do `ListView` na minha `Activity`:

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// Construindo dados fake, apenas para ter um ListView cheio
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();

    song.put("NUMERO", "" + i);

    songsListData.add(song);
}

ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.fpa_list);

// Crio o meu Adapter customizado, que herda de SimpleAdapter
mAdapter = new TestBaseAdapter(getActivity(), songsListData, R.layout.playlist_item, new String[]{"NUMERO"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

// Seto um OnItemClickListener apenas para delegar ao Adapter a atualizacao
// do ultimo item clicado e do numero de cliques
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mAdapter.updateClick(parent, view, position);
    }
});
```

Agora vem o **`SimpleAdapter`** que fiz para aplicar a regra de cliques:

```
public class TestBaseAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    // Armazena a quantidade de clicks em uma determinada linha e sua posicao
    int mUltimaPosicaoClicada = -1, mNumeroCliques = 0;

    // Usado para adicionar um valor a uma View, no metodo setTag
    int mResId;

    public TestBaseAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        mResId = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        updateBackground(view, position);

        // Guardo na View, sua posicao
        // Facilita ao fazer a limpeza manual do background caso seja necessario
        view.setTag(mResId, position);

        return view;
    }

    /***
     * Atualiza o background da View conforme a regra de cliques
     * @param view
     * @param position
     */
    void updateBackground(View view, int position) {
        if(position == mUltimaPosicaoClicada) {
            switch (mNumeroCliques) {
                case 0:
                    view.setBackgroundResource(0);
                case 1:
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.primary);
                    break;
                case 2:
                default:
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black_87p);
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(0);
        }
    }

    /***
     * Atualiza a ultima posicao clicada e o numero de cliques.
     * E atualiza o Background da view conforme o resultado
     * @param adapterView
     * @param view
     * @param position
     */
    public void updateClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position) {
        // Logica para guardar o numero de cliques e o ultimo item clicado
        if(mUltimaPosicaoClicada == position) {
            mNumeroCliques++;
        } else {
            mUltimaPosicaoClicada = position;
            mNumeroCliques = 1;
        }

        // Podemos usar o "notifyDataSetChanged", com isso todas as Views
        // que estao visiveis serao reconstruidas
        // notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Ou podemos atualizar manualmente as visiveis, as demais
        // serao construídas pelo Adapter
        updateVisibleViews(adapterView);
    }

    void updateVisibleViews(AdapterView adapterView) {
        for(int i = 0, childCount = adapterView.getChildCount(); i < childCount; ++i) {
            View view = adapterView.getChildAt(i);
            int position = (Integer) view.getTag(mResId);

            updateBackground(view, position);
        }
    }
}
```

Gostaria de deixar uma observação:

No método `updateClick` do `TestAdapter`, deixei a atualização dos itens podendo ser feita de duas formas:

1. Usar o `notifyDataSetChanged` para forçar a atualização de todos as `View's` visíveis por parte do `ListView`. Isso vai forçar que o método `getView` seja chamado denovo para todos os itens visíveis. Pode não ser uma boa alternativa se a construção dos itens forem complexos, causando um "overhead".
2. Atualizar manualmente as `View's` que estão visíveis. Isso é bem mais performático, porém envolve adicionar uma lógica extra. Nesse caso eu adicionei a posição do item como uma tag no `View.setTag` dentro do método `getView`, para tornar fácil a atualização depois no método `updateVisibleViews` no `TestAdapter`.

Comment: Funcionou,porém dessa forma ele apenas permite marcar um por vez, eu preciso selecionar mais de uma opção, estou trabalhando para conseguir fazer isso, mas se puderem me ajudar ficaria agradecido de toda forma, vou aceitar a resposta, por que ja ajudou bastante...

Comment: @DiogoOdelli eu tinha pensando nisso. Minha primeira tentativa ia ser dessa forma, mas depois vi que sua lógica não era assim. Posso te ajudar sim, a ideia é trocar as duas flags por um `SparseArray`, mas como seria a lógica pra desmarcar?

Comment: Eu tenho uma lista, cada item da lista é um indice, que vou usar posteriormente.Quando clico na linha, é o primeiro indice, se eu clicar novamente nesta linha, ela precisar se desmarcada.
Se eu clicar em outra linha com a primeira linha marcada, ele precisa selecionar a outra linha também, que vai ser um segundo indice. Ou seja se a linha estiver marcada e for clicado ela desmarca, como se fosse um checkbox...
Não sei se fui claro.

Comment: se tu ajudar esse o link da aplicação postada na playstore com esse bug, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ssMultiTrack.android ...

Comment: @DiogoOdelli, atualizei, ve se ajuda como eu fiz. Você pode trocar o `SparseArray<Integer>` para `SparseArray<Boolean>` para ficar melhor ainda. Só fazer as adaptações necessárias.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, esse é meu trabalho de conclusão de curso, to apanhando um pouco para as listviews, vou colocar teu nome nas dedicatórias...kkk vlw

Comment: @DiogoOdelli, muito legal :) Meu projeto final também foi um app Android. Ralei muito pra fazer, aprendi muito. Essa é uma boa motivação pra aprender essa plataforma, que é muito rica e a cada dia aprendo mais. Boa sorte nos estudos e tente seguir os tutoriais do Android, eles possuem um material muito rico.

Comment: realmente, muito coisa pra fazer a aprender, pretendo me especializar em android, e mais uma vez muito obrigado pela ajuda...